# Отображение чисел Delphi7

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте, прошу подсказать.
есть формула в дельфи, при расчете, ответ записывается в **Label44**.

```
label44.Caption:=FloatToStr((StrToFloat(edit9.Text))*(StrToFloat(edit4.Text))*((StrToFloat(edit10.Text))*(1*exp(-9*ln(10)))));
```

ответ который мне выводит, имеет следующий вид:  **1,10002875434028E-21**
возможно ли это число отобразить как **1,100028*10^-21**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То есть, просто сделать замену `E` на `^`.

```
x := StrToFloat(edit9.Text);
y := StrToFloat(edit4.Text);
z := StrToFloat(edit10.Text);
label44.Caption:=StringReplace(FloatToStr(x*y*z*exp(-9*ln(10))), 'E', '^', [rfIgnoreCase]);
```